# Tool tip for "No hats for me, please" button needs to be in sentence case

Tags: bug, status-planned, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021, capitalization

The tool tip for the button <kbd>No hats for me, please</kbd> isn't in sentence case and reads as:

> opt out of Winter Bash

To comply with Stacks standards, which require sentence case for UI elements, it needs to updated as:

> Opt out of Winter Bash

Screenshot:

[image: camelcase]

Answer (score 6):

**This FR is correct** because tooltips consistently use sentence casing in other parts of the site. For reference see the Stacks style guide on [Use sentence casing](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#use-sentence-casing), as shown in the screenshot:

[image: screenshot of tooltips]

Comment: Looks convincing. Are you going to write a userscript to find inconsistent tooltips? :P

Comment: @Glorfindel first I have to finish the userscript that finds pluralization bugs :)

Comment: [status-planned] for this year?

Comment: @Glorfindel ^^ see DebanjanB's question, perhaps Yaakov's comment shouldn't have been deleted.

Comment: @DebanjanB had already read that. I think they're asking *you* about the status of that user script :)

Comment: @Glorfindel I'll but only after 5 ticks on my comment ;)